# Linq Query To Return Complex Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a pretty standard model for Users and Roles:

```
+-------+   +-----------+   +-------+
| Users |   | UserRoles |   | Roles |
+-------+   +-----------+   +-------+
| ID (P)| < | UserID (P)|   | ID (P)|
| ...   |   | RoleID (P)| > | ...   |
+-------+   +-----------+   +-------+
```

I am using the Entitiy framework as my ORM and I am trying to construct - in a single Linq query - my ViewModel, definied below:

```
public class RoleDetail {
  public class RoleUser {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
  }
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Rolename { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<RoleUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I figured that the following query should work:

```
var query = Context.Roles
                   .Include("Users")
                   .Where(r => r.ID == id)
                   .Select(r => new RoleDetail() {
                      ID = r.ID,
                      Rolename = r.Rolename,
                      Active = r.Active,
                      Users = r.Users
                               .Select(u => new RoleDetail.RoleUser() {
                                  ID = u.ID,
                                  Username = u.Username
                                })
                                .ToList()
                    })
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, this throws the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List [RolesRepository+RoleDetail+RoleUser]
>   ToList[RoleUser]
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[RolesRepository+RoleDetail+RoleUser])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I haven't worked with Linq a lot, so I am quite sure that my query is wrong somehow.  Can someone show me where my query is going wrong and if there is a better way to accompish what I'm trying to achieve?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.ToList()` ?

Comment: That was the problem it appears.  Thanks to everyone leaving an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little experience with linq-to-entities, so this is a shot in the dark:

Why do you need .ToList()?

.Select() already returns an IEnumerable, so it should work without.

ToList() returns a List, not an IList or similar interface, but a concrete c# class. So I'd imagine that Linq to Entities cannot translate that into its own behind the scenes syntax

Does this work?

```
       var query = Context.Roles
               .Include("Users")
               .Where(r => r.ID == id)
               .Select(r => new RoleDetail() {
                  ID = r.ID,
                  Rolename = r.Rolename,
                  Active = r.Active,
                  Users = r.Users
                           .Select(u => new RoleDetail.RoleUser() {
                              ID = u.ID,
                              Username = u.Username
                            })
                            // .ToList()
                })
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Removing that did the trick - thank you!  I've been using .ToList() because otherwise my Entities class (instantiated/disposed via my repository constructor/destructor base class) gets disposed before the View can iterate the collection.  This is probably a whole other matter, but ToList() seems to work (usually).

Answer (score 2):

Everything in your LINQ query that gets sent off to the EF LINQ provider needs to be an expression that L2E can translate into SQL directly. It's up to you to manually separate the parts that EF can translate, from the parts that have to be done in LINQ 2 Objects.

The execution happens at the point where the query has to be actually enumerated, which in your case is the `FirstOrDefault` call. You can force the query to be executed earlier by calling `IQueryable.AsEnumerable()`; anything after that is processed by LINQ 2 Objects and can pretty much do whatever you want.

In your case, the only non-translatable aspect of your lambda expression is the call to `ToList`, which has no database equivalent, so you could simply not call that; the downside to this is that your `Users` property will be set up some arbitrary internal class that happens to be the result of `IQueryable.Select` in the EF's implementation. That may or may not be a problem for you, depending on what you defined `RoleDetail.Users` as and what you do with it.

The alternative, and the more generally-applicable solution when you have to process an expression that EF doesn't like, is to insert the `AsEnumerable` call early:

```
var query = Context.Roles
           .Include("Users")
           .Where(r => r.ID == id)
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(r => new RoleDetail() {
              ID = r.ID,
              Rolename = r.Rolename,
              Active = r.Active,
              Users = r.Users
                       .Select(u => new RoleDetail.RoleUser() {
                          ID = u.ID,
                          Username = u.Username
                        })
                        // .ToList()
            })
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Excellent explanation.  So once .AsEnumerable is called, the query is dealing with the actual entity objects vs. trying to create a db friendly SQL query?  That makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes. The EF LINQ sequence operators return `IQueryable` objects; these just contain an `Expression` which has yet to be compiled (and will never be, it will be used to produce a SQL query). Once you call a method that doesn't return an `IQueryable`, EF has to parse the expression, execute the SQL, and produce an object/sequence. Once that's done, EF is out of the picture.

Comment: Which probably explains why my controller returning an IQueryable object to my view was throwing an error - the db context was out of scope and the actual SQL hadn't been executed yet?

Comment: Yes, and that's also why you need the `Include` call; as long as the context is in scope, it will lazy-load any navigation properties you use but once that context has been disposed, any data you haven't already retrieved is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's trying to execute **ToList** at the database and not knowing how.  I would try changing it to **ToArray**, or failing that, just leaving it as IEnumerable.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the assist.  I accepted based on the first answer, though all where helpful.